# Does Ractive apply CSS styles to called partial?

Tags: html, css, partial, ractivejs

I'm trying to factorise some code in my `HTML`. I have a custom tree component (a `Ractive` component) in which the node of the tree is a partial as follows:

```
<!-- {{>node}} -->
<li class='node'>
    {{#data}}
    <span class='MyClass'>  
        {{>content}}
        Some text
    </span>
    {{/data}}
<!-- {{/node}} -->
```

In my `CSS`, I have:

```
.active
{
  color: red; 
}
```

Note: `{{>content}}` is a `Ractive` native directive that calls some data.

As a result, once the html is rendered, the content displayed once the directive `{{>content}}`is resolved is not red, but the "Some text" is red.

Have I missed something, or is it not possible? As a workaround, I can move the span directly in the calling code, but I will have to do it for any code using this partial. I'd like to avoid it if possible.

**EDIT**: Here is the calling code (simplified content of my HTML source file):

```
<Tree>
    <a href="#" on-click="select">
        {{name}}
    </a>
</Tree>
```

Comment: Is `>content` wrapped in HTML tags?

Comment: I've just edited to add the content that is called

Comment: You have an anchor inside span and you are adding class .active to span. You will have to write `.active, .active * {color:red}` to override the default color of anchor. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/fvv1098t/1/)

Comment: Ok, so it was a misunderstanding of CSS, not of Ractive. Thanks for your help!